# Wire library giving false readings on Arduino Uno (I²C)

Tags: arduino, i2c, arduino-uno

I'm trying to get I²C communication working between a Raspberry Pi using the python-smbus package and an Arduino Uno using the Wire library.

I'm currently sending one byte from the raspi to the arduino, which stores it and then sends it back upon the request of the raspi.

This works very well at first, but a few seconds after starting the script (around 500 to 4000 sending/reading cycles), the arduino will start to get false readings. These persist until the arduino is restarted, and restarting the python script and/or the raspberry pi doesn't make a difference either. For this reason, I'm sure that the problem is on the side of the arduino.

By using the serial monitor, I've determined that the arduino actually does receive (or thinks it receives) this wrong number.

The number is wrong in a very specific way: It is left shifted by one and a one is appended to its end.

If there's any additional information you'd like, please do tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a logic analyzer you can put on the I2C bus to see what is happening there?

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit that anymore. Map: `0x0A(0x05 W) 0x0B(0x05 R)` Working: `[0x0A+0x02+][0x0B+0x01-[]` Not working: `[0x0A+0x02+][0x0B+0x03-[]` This is interesting - I actually am trying to send `1` with the pi.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format you are using, and it is a bit confusing in a comment. Can you put it in your answer in a clearer format? What are the differences between the working and not working observations? Which bits are clock, and which are data?

Comment: This is using the Bus pirate: [ start  //  ] end  //  0xAB - data // + ack // - nack // What the pi is sending is recognized as a 2, but is a 1 in code. The arduino responds with 1 at first, but with 3 later on.

Comment: I am not familiar with Bus Pirate, and in any case diagnosis needs more detail about the timing of clock and data.

Comment: Using 100kHz. Data is sending 0x01 and then requesting, which should respond the same.

Comment: I used a logic analyzer. The results can be seen [here](https://imgur.com/YdxAyko,SWf6amb). It looks like something is pulling the data low. In fact, this might well be the raspi since it goes back up when necessary.

Comment: FYI: The long block in the middle is interpreted as 3+ACK

Comment: I have not seen prolonged clock high, data low before. The block starting shortly before 0.9 ms looks to me like a normal stop-idle-start sequence.

Comment: I think that the problem is the raspi "forgetting" to put the data high again. That doesn't explain why it's always at this point, though.

Comment: The device does not have to put the data high - both clock and data should have pull-up resistors that put them high in the idle state. One of those signals is low if, and only if, at least one device is forcing it low.

Comment: Can you use the logic analyzer to find out if the prolonged data low, clock high condition happens only just before the failure? It will happen briefly during a normal start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75607/discussion-between-patricia-shanahan-and-humanoid).